# Chamada de duas colunas e inner join

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, inner-join

Estou dando os meus primeiros passos no SQL e estou com dificuldade ao montar uma query.

Tenho duas tabelas e a primeira `tab1` possui o código da cidade `CodCid` e o nome da cidade `NumCid`. A segunda `tab2` possui os códigos das cidades de origem e destino `CodCidOrig` e `CodCidDest`.

Como estou montando uma query grande e preciso ter o nome das cidades de destino e origem para outros processos fiz:

```
  select NumCid as cidade_de_origem, 
         NumCid as cidade de destino 
    from tab1 
   inner join tab2 on CodCid in (CodCidOrig, CodCidDest)
```

Usando esta query cria-se uma coluna em que a primeira linha são duas cidades iguais de origem, em seguida com duas cidades iguais de destino e assim por diante, tendo o mesmo padrão (duas origens iguais e duas de destino iguais).

O banco é relacional então `CodCid` é igual a `CodCidOrig` e `CodCidDest`.

Comment: Faz um favor, de uma lida em Como Fazer um [MCVE]. Depois dê mais detalhes das estruturas das tabelas e dos resultados obtidos e pretendidos, mais uma amostra, curta e em texto, de dados para testes.

Comment: Pode deixar! Farei isso!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você precisa relacionar duas vezes a tabela tab1. Dê apelidos para elas. A consulta abaixo deve resolver.

```
select *
from tab2 
  inner join tab1 cidade_ori on cidade_ori.CodCidOrig = tab2.CodCid
  inner join tab1 cidade_dest on cidade_dest.CodCidDest = tab2.CodCid
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sua ajuda foi muito boa! Me ajudou a solucionar o problema!